# Python, mutating list that has a bool using a function. Taking negation of bool returns 1 or 2?

Tags: python, list, boolean

```
def copy_me(input_list):
    ''' (list) -> list
    This function will copy the list and will do the following to it:
    change every string into an upper case, increase the value of every
    integer and float by 1, negate every boolean and replace lists with the
    word 'List'. After the modifications are made, the copied list will be
    returned. (The original inputted list won't be mutated)
    REQ: The list must only contain the following data types: str, int,
    float, bool, list.

    >>> copy_me(['hi', 1, 1.5, True, ['sup', 123])
    ['HI', 2, 2.5, False, 'List']
    '''
    # Copy the list
    copied_list = input_list.copy()

    # Go through each element of list
    for index, element in enumerate(copied_list):
        print(type(element))

        if (type(element) == str):
            copied_list[index] = element.upper()
        elif (type(element) == int or float):
            copied_list[index] = element + 1
        elif (type(element) == bool):
            if (element == True):
                copied_list[index] = False
            elif (element == False):
                copied_list[index] = True
    print(copied_list)
```

doing something like:

```
>>> copy_me([True])
[2]
```

That makes no sense to me. Can anyone explain why and how I can get it to return False as the value?

Comment: `type(element) == int or float` [doesn't mean what you think it means](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/748858).  That gets parsed as `(type(element) == int) or float)`.  Since `float` is truthy, that branch will _always_ execute unless a branch above it already executed...

Comment: Shouldn't float be false in the if statement regardless? But okay I think I get it thanks!

Comment: Nope.  In python _most_ things are truthy (including all builtin types).

Comment: Also, based on the "REQ" part, it looks like you're missing a chance to use recursion (e.g. if you get a list that holds another list!)  :-)

Comment: haven't learned recursion yet D:, but it should handle it properly where it'll get rid of the list entirely and replace it with 'List' ;D

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of things here that are problematic.  The first is:

```
type(element) == int or float
```

This has been asked about [multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/748858) so I won't answer in depth here.  The problem is that the expression is parsed as `(type(element) == int) or float)` -- and since `float` is truthy, that expression is always going to be truthy.  The fix is something like <sup>1</sup>:

```
type(element) == int or type(element) == float
```

This should be enough to get your code working, however, `isinstance` is much more idiomatic and can be used to clean this up significantly:

```
if isinstance(element, str):
    copied_list[index] = element.upper()
elif isinstance(element, bool):
    copied_list[index] = not element  # cleaner negation :-)
elif isinstance(element, (int, float)):  # numbers.Number might even be better...
    copied_list[index] = element + 1
```

Notice that I put the `bool` check before the `int, float` check.  The reason for this is because `bool` is an `int` subclass (which also explains how you got a `2` in your initial code:

```
True + 1 == 2
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Generally, I'd also advise using `isinstance(x, y)` rather than `type(x) == y`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You problem is in the condition:

```
type(element) == int or float
```

You are missing parentheses around the "int or float" part. So what the condition is checking is:
1. type(element) == int
2. float (always true.)

In general, it is recommended to use the function isinstance for type checking.

Comment: We haven't learned isinstance yet and we we're told not to use it for now :/ But makes perfect sense, thanks for the answer!